# MatrixForm control inside Row[]

Tags: output-formatting

I would like to pretty print two column vectors of different lengths so that they are aligned at the top rather than centered, which seems to be the default. For example,

```
v1 = {a, b, c, d, 0, 0, 0}; v2 = {a, b, c, d};
Row[{MatrixForm[v1], MatrixForm[v2]}, Alignment -> {Center, Top}]
```

results in the pretty printing of the vectors but they are actually centered in the row rather than aligned with the horizontal position at the top.

Using a GraphicsRow instead of Row does work but changes the fonts from the rest of the nb so is only a second best solution.

Is there some other approach to this that I could try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
v1 = {a, b, c, d, 0, 0, 0}; v2 = {a, b, c, d};
Grid[{{MatrixForm[v1], MatrixForm[v2]}}, Alignment -> Top]
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, apologies that this was so easy.

Comment: Alignment is also an option for Row so I don't really understand why this works for Grid and not Row?

Comment: @pjc42 It is alignment within the total ImageSize of Raw, not for each element.

Comment: Got it, many thanks.